# About Json Post with Auth

Tags: 1c

I have a question.
I want to post json. It contains user information. I want to read the returned Json data.
I wrote sample code. Where is my mistake? How can I do it?

example url : "api.abc.com/getlist/"

jsoninput = {

```
      "MERCHANT":"merchid",
      "MERCHANT_KEY":"merchkey",
      "START_DATE":"2022-01-01",
      "END_DATE":"2022-02-02"
   
}
```

My Code :

```
    ServerAdress = "api.abc.com";
Resource = "getlist";
ssl1 = new OpenSSLSecureConnection(Undefined, Undefined);
HTTP = New HTTPConnection(ServerAdress,443,,,,10,ssl1);


HTTPRequest = New HTTPRequest("getlist");
HTTPRequest.Headers.Insert("Authorization", jsoninput);
HTTPRequest.Headers.Insert("Accept",  "application/json");
       HTTPRequest.Headers.Insert("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       HTTPRequest.Headers.Insert("Accept-Language",  "en_US");
       HTTPRequest.Headers.Insert("Cache-Control",    "no-cache");
       HTTPRequest.SetBodyFromString("grant_type=client_credentials");
Connection = New HTTPConnection("api.abc.com",,,,,10,New OpenSSLSecureConnection);

       JSONReader = New JSONReader;
 
Try        
           HTTPAnswer = Connection.Post(HTTPRequest); // post Request
           JSONReader.SetString(HTTPAnswer.GetBodyAsString());
       Data = ReadJSON(JSONReader, False);
           message(Data);
       Except
   ErrorText = "Sending " + ErrorDescription();
   message(ErrorText);
EndTry;
```

Comment: 1c enterprise platform.

Comment: Damn, son, only one question with `1c` tag on whole entire site...

Comment: Highly recommend you to ask this at ru.stackowerflow.com, because 1c is russian program

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
structureInput = New Structure;
structureInput.Insert("MERCHANT",       "merchid");
structureInput.Insert("MERCHANT_KEY",   "merchkey");
structureInput.Insert("START_DATE",     "2022-01-01");
structureInput.Insert("END_DATE",       "2022-02-02");


JSONWriter = New JSONWriter;
JSONWriter.SetString();
WriteJSON(JSONWriter, structureInput);

jsoninput = JSONWriter.Close();
```

and then:

```
HTTPRequest.Headers.Insert("Authorization", jsoninput);
```